# I am running a scheduled map function - but it ends up clearing my array instead

Tags: reactjs

I have a to do list practice application built.

There are tasks with a priority, and the initial state is as follows:

```
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
    {
      "text": "Task 1",
      "priority": false,
    },
    {
      "text": "Task 2",
      "priority": false,
    },

]);
```

I'm trying to run a scheduled job at a certain time to set all priorities to false - i.e. i'll map through the tasks array and set priority to false.

```
  const clearPrioritiesJob = schedule.scheduleJob('0 0 0 * * *', () => {

    setTasks(tasks.map((task) => {
    console.log(tasks)
    return { ...task, priority: false}}));

    clearPrioritiesJob.cancel();

  });
```

However, I when I run this, I can see that the console.log runs 4 times - it shows that the priorities were not cleared, and eventually the result is an empty array.

See image below for the logs in the console

[image: Empty array in logs]

Could someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing in your question indicates why the tasks array eventually becomes empty, there is something else in your component causing that to happen. You'll need to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get help with that.

Answer (score 2):

With the code you provided, it is hard to say what is wrong.

If the callback `() => setState(...))` is stored somewhere, maybe you are refering to stale `tasks` state in the `setTasks(tasks.map(...))`.

To make sure you are always acceccing the latest state, you can do

```
setState((upToDateTasksState) => {
   return upToDateTasksState.map(...);
});
```

Comment: I think I know what's wrong  - I was testing this code out only in the UI but the rest of my code is writing/reading directly from the DB using async functions. I suppose that's what's causing this issue?